# Something is wrong with a query syntax for bcp command in SQL

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm building a query for my bcp command in SQL.
When executing the statement I have the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT
>   'Transaction Unique ID','Transaction Date', 'Person Unique ID' 
>             UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS 'Transaction Unique ID',
>   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS              ' Transaction
>   Date', NULL AS 'Person Unique ID' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE
>   YYYYMM = ' to data type int.

This is the syntax for my bcp command:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @bcpCommand VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @sharedDevFolder VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @environment VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @customerCode VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @parserConfig VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @bucketAssign VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @dateFormat VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @RC int

SET @sharedDevFolder = '\\REMOTE_SERVER\MyDirectory\'
SET @input = 201507
SET @fileName = 'Transaction-' + 
                @environment + '-' + 
                @customerCode + '-' + 
                @parserConfig + '-' + 
                @bucketAssign + '-' + 
                @dateFormat + '.txt'

SET @query = 
    'SELECT ''Transaction Unique ID'',''Transaction Date'', ''Person Unique ID'' UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS ''Transaction Unique ID'', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS '' Transaction Date'', NULL AS ''Person Unique ID'' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = ' + CAST(@input as VARCHAR(10))

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "' + @query + '" queryout "'
set @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @sharedDevFolder + @fileName + '" -c  -T -t^| -r\n'

EXEC @RC = master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.

When executed, the following query is printed:

```
SELECT 'Transaction Unique ID','Transaction Date', 'Person Unique ID' UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS 'Transaction Unique ID', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS 'Transaction Date', NULL AS 'Person Unique ID' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = '201507'
```

I have been trying to solve it for sometimes already and it's really bugging me.

Can you please explain what I'm doing wrong and if possible provide me with the correct way of doing this?

Comment: On which line of this query do you get that error message? And can you verify that this is the *actual* query being executed (except perhaps the sharedDevFolder value), and not something you've changed for this question? For instance, can you verify that the type of @input is really a varchar and that you're really using this variable when creating @query, and that the line setting @query does not use `... ' + 201507` and you just thought that a variable looks nicer?

Comment: Just a tip, but rather than single quotes, try square brackets ([, ]) for your identifiers.

Comment: There is no line indicator. Just `bcp` command is not executing

Comment: What is the type for the YYYYMM column?

Comment: It is an `int`, and I already changed it to `CAST(@input as VARCHAR(10))`

Comment: print the bcp line, and show that...and run the generated command manually and see what appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a data type mismatch going on.  The `+ @input` at the end of your query is the issue.

I'm guessing the column `[YYYYMM]` is a number?  It should be a string/varchar.

So your line could be

```
declare @input as varchar
set @input = '201505'
set @query = 'SELECT ''Transaction Unique ID'',''Transaction Date''...WHERE YYYYMM = ''' + @input + ''''
```

if `[YYYYMM]` is a string, or if it's not and it's numeric

```
declare @input as int
set @input = 201505
set @query = 'SELECT ''Transaction Unique ID'',''Transaction Date''...WHERE YYYYMM = ' + cast(@input as varchar)
```

Comment: I have it the 2nd way, exactly the same as you showed, and it still does not work. I updated my question with a query output. I print the final query out. May be this can give some clue of what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the query 'SELECT ''Transaction...' is varchar and input is represented as INT although it is varchar. Use :

```
    SET @query = 
'SELECT ''Transaction Unique ID'',''Transaction Date'', ''Person Unique ID'' UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS ''Transaction Unique ID'', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS '' Transaction Date'', NULL AS ''Person Unique ID'' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @input) + ''''
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still has a `NULL` as an output. The statement, if executed, supposed to create a file, but it does not.

Comment: @gene what does it do then?

Comment: I updated my question with the final query output. It looks just fine to me.

Comment: I found the problem, but not sure how to fix it. The problem is in @filename variable. The bcp does not recognize the string used. I'm trying to compose the right string combination, but it does not seem to be working –

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The problem was I did not set variables used to build the file name. When bcp was executing, the file name was not built correctly